# Why can't I open the image show again when I have destroy all the image windows in Raspiberry?

Tags: python, camera, kivy

A app with kivy in the Raspiberry. Call the cv2.namedWindow and crop the capture image. Then the program goes well. But when I turn back and want to take the image again, I can't open the image window again. The program is broken. It has no effect when I click any button. I think maybe the windows name need to be different. So I destoryAllWindows for the first time, and create again with different windows name, it can't open the image windows. And the program is also broken. But the program works good in the windows system. Is it limited for raspiberry ram?
The app program:

```
def capture(self, stop_event):
    ...
    App.camera = cameraControl.KivyCamera()
    App.camera.take_image()
    ...
```

The camera program:

```
class KivyCamera(Image):
    ...
    def on_mouse(self.event,x,y,flags,params):
        img2 =self.image.copy()
        if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
            point1 = (x,y)
            cv2.circle(img2,point1,10,(0,255,0),5)
            cv2.imshow(self.window_name, img2)
        elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE and (flags & cv2.EVENT_FLAG_LBUTTON):
            cv2.rectangele(img2, point1,(x,y),(255,0,0),5)
            cv2.imshow(self.window_name, img2)
        elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
            point2 = (x,y)
            cv2.rectangle(img2,point1,point2,(0,0,255),5)
            cv2.imshow(self.window_name,img2)
            ...

    def take_image(self):
        ...
        camera_image = io.BytesIO(file_data)
        camera_image.seek(0)
        image = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(camera_image.read(), np.uint8),cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        slef.image = cv2.flip(image, -1)
        cv2.imwrite(capture_path, self.image)
        self.window_name = str(time.time())
        cv2.namedWindow(self.window_name,cv2.WINDOW_KEEPRATIO)
        cv2.setMouseCallback(self.window_name,self.on_mouse)
        cv2.imshow(self.window_name,self.image)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```